# jQuery UI. Как сделать слайдер с НЕ равным шагом.

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript, html, css

```
        <script>
$(function(){
    //slider range
  var sliderRange = $('#slider-range');
  var sliderMin = 0;
  var sliderMax = 12;
  var sliderStart = sliderMin;
  var sliderEnd = sliderMax;
  var sliderStep = 1;

  $('#min').val(sliderMin);
  $('#max').val(sliderMax);
  $('#start').val(sliderStart);
  $('#end').val(sliderEnd);
  $('#step').val(sliderStep);
 // $('#amount').text(sliderStart +' - '+ sliderEnd +' р.');

  sliderRange.slider({
    range: true,
    min: sliderMin,
    max: sliderMax,
    step: sliderStep,
    values: [sliderStart, sliderEnd],
    slide: function(event, ui){
     // $('#amount').text(ui.values[0] +' - '+ ui.values[1] +' р.');

        $('#start').val(ui.values[0]);
        $('#end').val(ui.values[1]);
    }
  });

});
        </script>
    <div class="slider_vals">
        <div id="slider-range" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="start" id="start" value="0.8"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="end" id="end" value="8.5"/>
```

Сейчас заданы параметры, что шагов 12, один шаг - 1. Значение идут в скрытый инпут. Мне же нужно, чтобы было не 1, 2, 3.. и так до 12, а 0.9, 1, 1.5, 1.8, 2, 3... и т.д. в общем. Помогите, пожалуйста сделать. Мне уже подсказывали делать, мол если значение слайдера 1, то реальное значение 0.9, которое мы вставляем в инпут. Но у меня ничего не вышло...

Comment: У слайдер есть такая штука, как change. Создаем объект, свойство которого будут равны значеням слайдера, а значения свойства будет равно нужному вам значению. Собственно при событии change делаем наше дело :-)

Comment: @lampa а, ну "понятно", особенно если учесть, что я в js не совсем ноль, но...)) Можно на примере плиз?

Comment: @inferus-vv http://jsfiddle.net/nYTa4/

Comment: А вообще вот тут люди обсуждали: http://habrahabr.ru/qa/19407/

Comment: @lampa Вот проблема в том, что на любых значениях мне выдает 0.9. Та же проблема была, когда я делал своим способом.

Comment: @inferus-vv тот скрипт, что я выложил на jsfiddle должен удовлетворять вашим требованиям, т.к. он правильно работает.

Comment: @lampa Он не работает вообще.. Не отображаются ползунки.

Comment: @lampa Вот:

$(function(){
 var ArrValues = {
  0:0.9,
  1:1.5,
  2: 2.8,
  3:7.4,
  4:9.2,
  5:15.4
 }
 $('#slider-range').slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 12,
  step: 1,
  values: [0, 12],
  change: function() {
   alert(ArrValues[$(this).slider("value")]);
  }
 });
});

Все время 0.9 выводит

Answer (score 3):

[@inferus-vv](/users/6278/inferus-vv) ах у вас же `range: true`.

Получается так и красивее:

```
change: function(event, ui) { 
    alert(ArrValues[ui.value]); 
}
```

Comment: А как передавать в одно первый ползунок, а второй игпут - второй. Попробовал так:
change: function(event, ui) { 
   console.log(ArrValues[ui.value]);
   $('#start').val(ArrValues(ui.values[0]));
   $('#end').val(ui.values[1]);
  }

Но не выходит

Comment: Вы всё правильно делали:

$('#start').val(ArrValues(ui.values[0])); 


$('#end').val(ArrValues(ui.values[1]));

Comment: а почему он мне какие то вначале странные значения выставляет ( start - 0.8, end - 8.5)? А при переключении ничего не происходит. В кончоли пишет Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: Ох, я скобки не доглядел. Зачем же вы заменили квадратные скобки на круглые?) Объект то не функция :-)

Comment: Спасибо, при переключении работает, но начальные значения (0.8 и 8.5 откуда? Вообще таких в коде нет..

Comment: Посмотрите свой код, у вас вначале идет:

  $('#start').val(sliderStart);



  $('#end').val(sliderEnd);

Comment: Я избавился от этого. Вот код текущий: http://jsfiddle.net/NJjtZ/

Comment: Вы опять невнимательны!) У вас стоит стандартное значение инпутов:

    <input type="hidden" name="start" id="start" value="0.8"/>


    <input type="hidden" name="end" id="end" value="8.5"/>